# How can I convert an integer to float value in textfield in swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

```
@IBOutlet weak var creditCardTXTField: UITextField!

 @IBOutlet weak var phoneNUmberTxtField: UITextField!
```

I have two `UITextFields` .When I enter a number in the first `textfield` it should return a float value. for eg if I enter 15 it should return 15.00. This should happen when i click the second `UItextfield`. (`didEndEditing` method is used here)

Comment: with textfield.text , it returns string value .. .you have to convert it into float

Comment: In didEndEditing, append `.00` with textfield value and then convert final value to float e.g : `self. creditCardTXTField.text = self. creditCardTXTField.text! + ".00"`

Comment: Can you provide me the full code @Jigar tarsariya?

Comment: Yes please check my answer

Comment: As your question has been closed so not able to answer it. But I'm posting a link of my answer. Have a look and don't just copy .... Understand it Please. [Click me to see code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16651084/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display textfield value as a float like appending ".00" string with textField like,

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField)
{
     if(textField == self.phoneNUmberTxtField)
     {
           self.creditCardTXTField.text = String(format:"%.2f", (Float)(self.creditCardTXTField.text!)!)
     }

}
```

NOTE: this thing also possible with `textFieldShouldReturn` method.

Hope this will help you

Comment: I believe appending ".00 " is not a solution.. If i give 34.5 the output will be 34.500. Instead the output should be 34.5 itself. @JIgar Tarsariya

Comment: Ohh, i got it so you can write like my edited answer. please check it.

Comment: @JigarTarsariya Now you copied from my code in comment. Well your code still has bug. Replace `if(textField == self.creditCardTXTField)` with `if(textField == self.phoneNUmberTxtField)` because he need this when he click on second field.

Comment: @TheTiger As Rakesh Mohan has explained me, i got the idea and change it as he need so no need to copy it because its common to convert string to float and assign it to string again.

Comment: @JigarTarsariya I'm not arguing.. Its ok. But sometimes copy paste left en error as you did. Also `String(format:"%.2f", (Float)(self.creditCardTXTField.text!)!)` here is an unwrapping error `!` I checked it later and you pasted the same so I said that. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate
{


@IBOutlet weak var one: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var two: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}



func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    let myInt = Int(one.text!)

    let myFloat = Float(myInt!)

    two.text = ("\(myFloat)")

}
}
```

Comment: i didn't make any check , you have to allow only numbers to be typed ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to convert your int value to float

```
let myInt = //your int value
let myFloat = Float(myInt)
```

Or to convert Float to Int you may use

```
var IntValue:Int = Int(FloatValue)
println "My value is \(IntValue)"

var myIntValue = Int(FloatValue)
```